# IE Issue: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference HYPERLINK "0"ScriptResource.axd, line 172 character 17

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, sharepoint

This issue occurs only in IE 9 and 10 . We are using  SharePoint  2007 and facing an issue with Sharepoint induced function :

```
function ValidatorOnChange(event) {
    if (!event) {
        event = window.event;
    }
    Page_InvalidControlToBeFocused = null;
    var targetedControl;
    if ((typeof(event.srcElement) != "undefined") && (event.srcElement != null)) {
        targetedControl = event.srcElement;
    }
    else {
        targetedControl = event.target;
    }
    var vals;
    if (typeof(targetedControl.Validators) != "undefined") {
        vals = targetedControl.Validators;
    }
    else {
        if (targetedControl.tagName.toLowerCase() == "label") {
            targetedControl = document.getElementById(targetedControl.htmlFor);
            vals = targetedControl.Validators;
        }
    }
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
        ValidatorValidate(vals[i], null, event);
    }
    ValidatorUpdateIsValid();
}
```

There is a textbox with calendar control. When the date is set, this error occurs resulting in termination of JS execution. The result we see is that the calendar popped out is not closed.I believe the issue is being caused by vals.length not having any value at the time of execution of the validator  but not I'm sure why its occurring only on IE9 and IE 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the error is referring to vals.length, it is referring to some variable inside the ScriptResource.axd file. The best hope for fixing this is try debugging with IE Developer tools and to also do extensive Googling. Also try looking for any syntax issues with javascript that's being called before or on the same page as ScriptResource.axd, as sometimes these errors manifest in the ScriptResource.axd, but originated before. This error can be caused by some very random things as seen in [this forum post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1695242.aspx?ScriptResource%20axd%20file%20error).